# sed find and replace in xml with range

Tags: xml, replace, sed

I have a xml like text file with an array of value that should be replaced by another range of values this is the starting point

```
<tag1>
<tag2> \myvalue[0]<tag2>
<tag2> \myvalue[1]<tag2>
<tag2> \myvalue[2]<tag2>
</tag1>
```

that should became:

```
<tag1>
<tag2> \myvalue[20]<tag2>
<tag2> \myvalue[21]<tag2>
<tag2> \myvalue[22]<tag2>
</tag1>
```

are there methods to say replace 0 to 10 with 20 to 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` is not very good at arithmetic, so if you really need to perform any arithmetic, using `awk` would probably be better than using `sed`.  With the caveat that any approach that does not use an XML-aware tool is going to be complex or fragile, here is a slightly robust solution to the problem as stated:

```
awk '
  $1 == "<tag2>" {
     n=split($2,a, /[][]/); 
     if (a[2] ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
       a[2] += 20; a[2] = "[" a[2] "]";
       s=""; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) s=s a[i];
       $2 = s;
     }
  } 1'
```

In words: if the first token on a line is `<tag2>` and if the there is an integer embedded within square brackets in the second token, then add 20 to that integer, and print that line with the replacement integer; otherwise, just print the line. (The final `1` is in effect shorthand for `{print}`.)